# Sqoop cannot export with update-mode in cloudera 5.8.0

Tags: sqoop

sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx --username xxxxx --password 
xxxxxxx --table xxxx --update-mode allowinsert --update-key xxxxx --export-dir 
xxxx --input-fields-terminated-by ','

Comment: ERROR :Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Sqoop and it is getting fixed in Version 1.4.7. Only the `updateonly` update mode works fine while exporting data to Oracle. Refer [SQOOP-2990](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2990).

Comment: Thanks for the update and can you provide me any documentation for upgrading sqoop 1 client in cloudera from 1.4.6 to 1.4.7

Comment: @Rohith `1.4.7` has not been released yet.

Comment: So is their any way to incremental export to oracle with sqoop

Comment: AFAIK, we do not have an alternative solution similar to `allowinsert` in export.